# How do I make a program that checks if there are two of the same characters in a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I need a program that checks if ther are two or more same charactars in a string. The don't have to be right next to each other like bb they can be farther apart like Bob. They just have to have the same charactar once or more.

What I have now doesn't work because it automatically says cool has two of the same charactars:

```
import collections
word = 'cool'
c = collections.Counter(word)
if c>1:
>>>>print (word,'has two of the same charactars:')
else:
>>>>print (word,'has no same charactars:')
```

Comment: Take the `word` as an input from the user, or read it from a file!

Comment: None of that helps and I will take the word as an input. Also ys they are spaces I will fix it later. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just need the .values() method of Counters.  The following tests both cases.

```
import collections
def dupchar(word):
    c = collections.Counter(word)
    return any(i >= 2 for i in c.values())
for word in 'hot', 'cool':
    print('{} has {} same characters'.format(word,
                'two of the' if dupchar(word) else 'no'))
```

prints

```
hot has no same characters
cool has two of the same characters
```